# Какой виджет использовать для быстрого вывода строк в Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Здравствуйте, нужно выводить очень быстро (каждые 1-10 миллисекунд) строки на экран. Сначала использовал для этого QPlainTextEdit, но он не особо подошёл под такую задачу т.к. количество отображаемых строк фиксировано (1000) и с помощью него плохо удалять первые строки. Сейчас использую QListWidget, но он очень медленный для такой задачи. Думал сделать свою модель для QListView, основанную на цикличном буфере, но при выводе на виджет всё-равно приходится заниматься удалением/вставкой элементов (т.е. гонять много памяти). Может кто сталкивался с такой задачей, посоветуйте вариант реализации.

Comment: На подавляющем большинстве мониторов, обновление 60 раз в секунду, т.е. около 16мс на кадр. Смысл чаще обновлять, если увидеть это будет невозможно?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian может я немного неправильно сформулировал задачу. Хочу найти подходящий виджет для вывода строк (пакетов) максимально быстро и легко. Использоваться будет в терминале последовательного порта, который отправляет/принимает данные с интервалом вплоть до 5мс вполне адекватно, но вот с выводом проблемы.

Comment: Вам все 1000 надо отображать на экране? В том смысле, что сколько их видно за раз?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Да, все 1000, или другое кол-во выставленное в настройках. Когда 1000 набралось удаляется удаляется первый и добавляется новый, хотелось бы пристроить как-то RingBuffer, он бы идеально подошёл под эту задачу.

Comment: Мысль у вас правильная была - использовать свою модель для QListView, проблем с буфером не вижу. Можете подробнее описать что там отъедает у вас процессорное время?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian если честно, в Qt недавно и опыта использования QAbstractListModel нету. Пытался сделать свою модель, получилось всунуть буфер, но на этапе вывода элемента на виджет всё-равно получается обычное удаление/вставка, а не замена.

Comment: Вам нужно использовать вьюху, вместо виджета. Вьюха будет запрашивать только те данные, которые видны на экране в данные момент. Сложного в своей модели ничего нет, несколько методов всего надо определить своих, типа вернуть кол-во данных, сами данные по индексу, и ещё что-то, не помню. По крайне мере вы можете начать, если застопорится, выложите здесь код, можно будет разобраться.

Comment: Что-то не так у Вас. `QPlainTextEdit` прекрасно подходит для вывода логов. Лимит строк легко регулируется посредством `QPlainTextEdit::setMaximumBlockCount(int)`. Как только кол-во строк достигнет лимита, первые строки начнут удаляться автоматом. Модели же для часто обновляемых логов лучше не использовать вовсе, поскольку их обновление происходит достаточно медленно в связи с использованием сигналов и слотов.

Comment: @alexis031182 QPlainTextEdit немного не подходит под задачу, нужно иногда меня стили некоторых строк. Если подскажете как это сделать буду очень признателен.

Comment: @ArTTo, есть метод `QPlainTextEdit::setCurrentCharFormat(const QTextCharFormat&)`. Используйте его перед вставкой новой строки. Это самый простой способ. Можно ещё вставлять текст т.н. блоками. Там уже будет доступно более гибкое форматирование.